# Short story about an investigator trying to contact a man who refuses to see him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I would have read this short story around 1970 to 1990. I'm pretty sure I read it in an anthology like Galaxy or F&SF as that's all I read back then. I keep thinking it was titled "Notes from the field" but that must be an error. The story was mostly in the form of reports from this investigator back to his supervisor.

The investigator is trying to get a large amount of money to a man who desperately avoids him even though his family lives in poverty. The investigator follows him and finally discovers the man (whose father was a drunken musician, and whose mother raised him religiously) and forces himself to play piano in a honky tonk bar to make ends meet. Story ends with something like "he was his father's son".

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! From your description, it's not immediately obvious that this story has any sci-fi or fantasy elements. Could you edit your question to include any sci-fi/fantasy elements that the story may have? If there aren't any such elements, then I'm afraid the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Im pretty sure I read it in an anthology like Galaxy or F&SF. (that's all I read back then). I keep thinking it was titled "Notes from the field" but that must be an error, I've been looking for this for a long time. Sorry it is being seen as not SiFi, but it was there... maybe in a Fantasy format. The story was mostly in the form of reports from this investigator back to his supervisor.

Comment: @RichardParks I've edited the information into the question itself but I'm not sure if it is enough to qualify this as SFF-nal. It would help if you could remember anything specifically SFF-nal about this and [edit] it in.